# l-value expected: Calling a custom iterator from inside the host class

Tags: c++, iterator, lvalue

I made this test program to replicate the error from my actual code. The iterator works correctly when called in the main function when `stuff()` is commented out. `stuff()` makes the compiler throw an error. I guess the reason is that the host class is not an object at compile time... so not an l-value? Unfortunately I did not quite know what to google for to find an explanation on how to make something like this work.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{

    class Iterator;

public:

    Foo() { init(); }

    Iterator begin()
    {
    return Iterator(data);
    }

    Iterator end()
    {
    return Iterator(data+10);
    }

    void stuff()
    {
        for (auto i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
        {
            1 + 1;
        }
    }

private:

    class Iterator
    {

    public:

    Iterator(int* i)
    {
        current = i;
    }

    bool operator!=(Iterator& rhs)
    {
        return rhs.current != current;
    }

    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        current = ++current;
        return *this;
    }

    int* operator*()
    {
        return current;
    }

    private:

    int* current;
    };

    void init()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = i;
    }
    }

    int data[10];

};


int main()
{

    Foo foo;

    for (auto i : foo)
    {
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
itertest.cpp:31:31: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Foo::Iterator' and 'Foo::Iterator')
        for (auto i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
                               ~ ^  ~~~~~
itertest.cpp:49:7: note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
        bool operator!=(Iterator& rhs)
```

Comment: operator!= should be a `const` method, and its parameter should be a `const Iterator &`.

Comment: `current = ++current;` can be rewritten just as `++current`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ok,. But *why* is that the solution?

Comment: Because end() is a temporary value, an rvalue (loosely speaking), and temporary values cannot be passed as non-const references, only as const reference (you could use rvalue reference, but that's off-topic). Technically, you could get away with a non-const method, but since the != operator is not expected to modify its object, it should be a const method.